# Rails: Manually change order of choices in select() helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, helper

I've got the following `select()` form helper method:

```
select("treatment", "frequency_unit", { "hour" => "hour", "day" => "day", "week" => "week", "month" => "month", "year" => "year" })
```

The helper is organizing the choices seemingly randomly...I'd like it to maintain the order of the choices as I have them listed above.

How can I make that happen?

Here's the output of the code above:

```
<select id="treatment_frequency_unit" name="treatment[frequency_unit]">
  <option value="month">month</option>
  <option value="week">week</option>
  <option value="hour">hour</option>
  <option value="day">day</option>
  <option value="year">year</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the hash, go for an array

```
<%= select("treatment", "frequency_unit", %w{hour day week month year})%>
```